# Nginx Server block for Laravel not working as expected

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use the below server block to display a Laravel website.

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name 111.222.333.444;


    location /cat {
        alias /var/www/html/cat/public;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /mkr {
        alias /var/www/html/mkr/public;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

**Problem:**

I can access the homepage but all the other pages eg. `111.222.333.444/cat/faq` are not accessible via pretty URLs as Nginx is displaying a `404` error.

I'd like some insight concerning what I might be doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Look into your logfiles of `nginx` which normally has `access.log` and `error.log`.

Comment: @Thomas I have checked the logs. It not displaying anything when I load an URL `eg.` 111.222.333.444/cat/faq It is, however, displaying a 404 on the site.